# Wordpress enque the same script causes the setInterval not to work

Tags: functions, javascript

So I created an `idle-timeout.js` that will check the user total idle time.

And I loaded it with `admin_enqueue_scripts` then after the session timeout the user can re-login again with the popup modal so I thought I can just run the same script using `wp_login`.

My Issue is after running the second time the `setInterval` doesnt work anymore.

**idle-timeout.js**

```
(function() {
   let minutes = 15;
   let date = new Date().toLocaleString();

   let idleInterval = setInterval(checkIdleTime, 1000); // might be the issue

 function checkIdleTime() { // issue wont execute the second time
   const oldDate = new Date(date);
   const currentDate = Date.now();
   const secondsDifference = Math.floor((currentDate - oldDate) / 1000);

   if (secondsDifference >= minutes * 5) { // prod is 60 seconds
     clearInterval(idleInterval);
      // logout function here
   }
  }
})();
```

**functions.php**

```
function idle_timeout()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('idle-timeout-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 
  '/js/idle-timeout.js', array('wp-api'), _S_VERSION, true);
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'idle_timeout');

function relogin()
{
   idle_timeout(); // setInterval wont run from idle-timeout.js 
}

add_action('wp_login', 'relogin');
```

Been trying to solve this for hours now. Hope you guys can help thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "running the second time"? I suspect the problem is that you call `clearInterval` which stops your interval. Likewise the login screen is not an admin screen, so `admin_enqueue_scripts` doesn't work there. You need to use the appropriate login script enqueing hook. Your logout code is also missing so if the problem is in the missing code nobody can help you. Note that WP itself has a timeout that prompts you to login in a modal via wp heartbeat, you don't have to reinvent it from scratch.

Comment: @TomJNowell Hi sorry my question is not clear basically when the session timeout is met it will logout the user will fire clearInterval ->  AJAX call -> wp_logout() and then detect if a user relogin using `wp_login` i want to run the idle-timeout.js again and sorry if my english is not very good.

Comment: so the user is still on the same page and there are no redirects to the login page? Your question is missing critical parts of the code in both the JS and the PHP, you must edit it into your question using the edit link. Why are you implementing this? Where is the AJAX code?